# how to execute pl/sql stored procedure havaing sys_refcursor as out parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
create or replace procedure get_emp(p_deptno number,emp_det out sys_refcursor)
is
begin
open emp_det for select * from emp where deptno=p_deptno;
end;
/
```

how to pass parameters for sys_refcursor and how to print that result using anonymous blocks in oracle pl/sql

Answer (score 1):

Just declare a `REFCURSOR` variable and pass it to ur procedure

You can open

```
DECLARE
MYCUR SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
get_emp(123,MYCUR);
FOR I in MYCUR
LOOP
   -- ur statements
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Also like this using SQLPLUS. Output would be like you run a select query, with what ever sent in the cursor.

```
VARIABLE MYCUR REFCURSOR;
EXECUTE get_emp(:MYCUR);

print MYCUR;
```